# AJAX redirect to proper id within the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have page with step [wizard](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard) where all steps are on a single html template which can be navigated through page id like`"id='step-1'","id='step-2'"`. I want to create button on page-3 to send some data from input box and problem is when I press the button it redirects me to the very beginning of page namely on step1 which is on the top of html template but I need keep staying on step3. Is it possible to stay on same step after pressing button?
step.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% csrf_token %}


  {% block step1 %}

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td> 
    <div id="wizard" class="swMain">
            <ul class="anchor">
              <li><a href="#step-1" class="selected" isdone="1" rel="1">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 1<br>
                       <small>Generate</small>
                    </span>
                      </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-2" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="2">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 2<br>
                       <small>test</small>
                    </span>
                </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-3" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="3">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 3<br>
                       <small>generate server keys</small>
                    </span>                   
                 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#step-4" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="4">
                    <label class="stepNumber"></label>
                    <span class="stepDesc">
                       Step 4<br>
                       <small>create</small>
                    </span>                   
                </a></li>
            </ul>


      <div style="height: 312px;" class="stepContainer"><div style="display:    none;" class="content" 
             id="step-1">  
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1 Generate and Test Key </h2>
                <ul type="disk">

                </ul>
                <p><h3>Welcome!</h3>
                </p>
                <p>
               This wizard will help you 
                </p>
                <p>

                </p>                
                <div>

            </div>
            <div style="display: block;" class="content" id="step-2">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2> 

            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="content" id="step-3">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Content</h2> 

 <form class="form-horizontal" id="your-form-id" >

               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" id="1" class="form-control" 
                  placeholder="Your country short name,e.g US " pattern="^[_A-Z]{1,}$" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Province</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" id="k-prov" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Your province" required>
                </div>
              </div>

                <button type="submit" id = "vars-data-promt">Upload text</button>
<div class="col-md-3 ">
                  <button type="submit" method="POST"  id="s3-btn"
                  class="form-inline btn btn-info pull-left">Generate</button>
                </div>
                </form>


                <p>

                </p>                                
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="content" id="step-4">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4 Content</h2> 

                <div>
                    <form>
                    <h4>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Don't use `<form>`. Instead of using `<button type="submit"...`, you have to use `<button type="button"...`. You need to create a JS function and listen for that button click. When clicked, send AJAX call to server. `<button type="button"...` will not redirect user to anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, zulhfreelancer, seems it works but I should check it in my app...

Comment: Cool, awesome buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid redirecting page after submit I've wrote script that sends post requests from every steps within one above shown template like this:

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/url to send request to/",
        data:({ 
            key1:value1,
            key2:value2
            }),
        success: function(data) { 
            // do what you want after request
        } 
    });
   return false;  
});
```

Adding "return false;" makes wonder! It so simple but it really works!
NOTE: "return false;" should be after ajax func brackets closed.
[This](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-submit-a-form-without-rerload-or-redirect-the-page.2151997/) helped me.